# Mongo and Node.js find and aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB and I need to use the functions "find" and "aggregate" togheter. For example:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb')
mongo.MongoClient.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true }, function(errorConectDB, client) {
     dbo.collection(this._objectName).find(query,options).aggregate(agr).toArray(function(err,
         res) {....}) })
```

However, when I execute my code the following error appears:

TypeError: dbo.collection(...).find(...).aggregate is not a function

Is there any way to fix it? Do you recommend any other alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Use `$match` in `aggregate` instead of using `find` as explained here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

For example:

```
db.articles.aggregate(
    [ { $match : { author : "dave" } } ]
);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks you!